# Specifying where-and in Laravel's query builder

Tags: laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I have the following code which works:

```
$name = 'jhon';
$users = DB::table('account')->where('login', '=', $name)->get();
```

How would I specify the AND parameter so that I can query on multiple conditions?

```
$login = $request->login;
$password = $request->password;

$users = DB::table('account')->where([
    ['login', '=', $login],
    ['password', '=', $password]
])->get();
```

Doesn't work.

```
$users = DB::table('account')
    ->where('login', '=', $login and 'password', '=', $password)->get();
```

To clarify, I'm looking specifically for a query builder solution, not an Eloquent solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `where` method twice:

```
$users = DB::table('account')
->where('login', '=', $login)
->where('password', '=', $password)
->get();
```